# Bootstrap Leaves Too Much Offset on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried building a page with Bootstrap 3.3.6 and it works fine on laptop but when I simulate Mobile viewing on Chrome and other browsers I get too much offset as shown in the picture below:

**Current result**:

[image: Current result...]

**Expected result**:

[image: Expected result.]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           Some content...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
           Some content...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
           Some content...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried `<div class="container">` but it is still the same.
And the meta:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Can you share some code sample? By the way, the current result is much better than the expected one in terms of readability and pretty much everything apart from that offset. That will get fixed though once you share at least a line of code, hard to help without it.

Comment: @LubosMenus sorry about that. Thought I did. I have just done that.

Comment: I am trying to understand what's wrong with it but based on the code you shared, everything should work just fine. Here's a quick CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgopNP. Only thing I can think of right now is that you are not using proper styles for mobile view - 'col-md-3' sets the width only for medium screens, you need to specify width for small (sm) and extra small (xs) too, that could be causing it?

Answer (score 2):

The point of Bootstrap is that it's responsive, but you need to follow their conventions to make it so. `col-md-x` applies to "medium" screens. When you target mobile, you need to use `col-xs-x`. So a div with `class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"` means that on phone screens, the div will be 6 columns, and on desktop screens it will be 3 columns.

I recommend you read the docs, http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Relevant portion:

> The Bootstrap 3 grid system has four tiers of classes: xs (phones), sm (tablets), md (desktops), and lg (larger desktops). You can use nearly any combination of these classes to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

Comment: This is not solving my problem. By default grids are stacked on mobile device but as you suggested I have specified `col-xs-12` on the middle `div` after setting other to `hidden-xs` but still having the large offset.